# How to make an image search command for Discord.js?

Tags: node.js

Hi I have added a feature in my discord bot which searches and displays an image when !image. However, I have implemented the commando feature for my dice roll. Is there a way to make an image search command?

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); 
const request = require("request");

bot.on("message", function(message) {

const parts = message.content.split(" "); 

    if (parts[0] === "!image") {

        image(message, parts);

    }

});

function image(message, parts) {

    const search = parts.slice(1).join(" ");

    const options = {
        url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + search,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "text/html",
            "User-Agent": "Chrome"
        }
    };
    request(options, function(error, response, responseBody) {
        if (error) {
            return;
        }

        $ = cheerio.load(responseBody);

        const links = $(".image a.link");

        const urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr("href"));
        console.log(urls);
        if (!urls.length) {
            return;
        }

        message.channel.send( urls[0] );
    });

}
```